# Find value of variable when it is not set (timeoutlen)

Tags: variables

How can I find out the default value of a variable if it is not set? For example, the default timeout for the leader key is controlled by the `timeoutlen` variable, but if I do:

```
:echo timeoutlen
```

I get an "undefined variable" error. Is there any command to find out default values for variables like this?

Comment: I believe `timeoutlen` is an option, not a variable. Read the help on options. Try `:set timeoutlen?`

Answer (score 2):

For options, you can use the special syntax `&optionname` to echo its value. This is described in the help at [:h expr-option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-option)

So you would want to do: `:echo &timeoutlen`

Answer (score 1):

You could type `:set {option}?` to show the value of an option.

If you want to inspect where it was defined:

```
:verbose set timeoutlen?
```