# How do I find out the value of an option?

Tags: variables

How do I find out the value of an option? I tried:

```
:echo ignorecase
:echo g:ignorecase
:echo v:ignorecase
```

None of these work.

Comment: You asked [the same question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13231/1841) 6 months ago and @Christian already gave you the same answer... If you don't want to use google you could at least check your own history

Answer (score 4):

To find out the value of an option, use either:
`set option?` (e.g. add the questionmark to the option name)
or use `:echo &option`

This is described at [:h expr-option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-option)